# alert when a particular text appears in a div in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to enable some panels when a specific text appears in a div. For example when the text "This is a valid host" appears in a particular div the alert would be given and some elements should be enabled(which are disabled in begining). If no text appears then alert will be "Invalid host".I implemented the below code but everytime its showing alert saying "valid host , panels are enabled".
Here is my code:

```
<script>
 $("#divoutput").bind("DOMSubtreeModified" , function(){
 if (("#divoutput").innerhtml=="This a valid host")
 {alert ("valid host , panels are enabled");
 $('#text1').attr('disabled', false);
 $('#text2').attr('disabled', false);
 $('#text3').attr('disabled', false);
 $('#text4').attr('disabled', false);
 elseif (("#divoutput").innerhtml=="") 
 alert ("Invalid host , ");
 })
</script>
```

Comment: you included `elseif` inside `if`

Comment: You have several mistakes in your JavaScript. The one @Raviteja just mentioned, plus you are missing a closing `}` for the `if` block before `else if. Further, you are missing the `$` for your selector in your `if` statement.

Answer (score 0):

> There are invalid `selectors` and few more human errors in provided snippet

Go through the example provided below:

```js
$("#divoutput").bind("DOMSubtreeModified", function() {
  if (this.innerText == "This a valid host") {
    alert("valid host , panels are enabled");
  } else if (this.innerText == "") {
    alert("Invalid host , ");
  }
});
$('#btn').on('click', function() {
  var selctor = $("#divoutput");
  var html = selctor.text();
  if (html) {
    selctor.html('');
  } else {
    selctor.html('This a valid host');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="divoutput">Hello</div>
<Button id='btn' type='button'>Change</Button>
```

[Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/o8cyb35e/2/)

Answer (score 0):

You mean like this?

**HTML**:

```
<div id="text">This is a valid host</div>
<input type="radio" id="input" disabled="true">
<button id="button">Click</button>
```

**Javascript**:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#button').click(function(){
        if(document.getElementById('text').innerHTML == "This is a valid host"){
            $('#input').removeAttr("disabled");
            alert("Valid host , panels are enabled");
        } else {
            $('#input').attr("disabled", "true");
            alert("Invalid host");
        }
    });
});
```

Once you click the button, it will check if the "This is a valid host" text exists. If the text does exist, the radio button will be enabled.

Answer (score -1):

@abhishek,you have missed the braces in your code.try with below.Updated ur code.

```
$("#divoutput").bind("DOMSubtreeModified" , function(){
if (("#divoutput").innerhtml=="This a valid host")
{
     alert ("valid host , panels are enabled");
     $('#text1').attr('disabled', false);
     $('#text2').attr('disabled', false);
     $('#text3').attr('disabled', false);
     $('#text4').attr('disabled', false);
}
else if (("#divoutput").innerhtml== " ")
{
  alert ("Invalid host");
}

 });
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do it like this:

```js
$("#divoutput").on("DOMSubtreeModified", function() {
  if ($(this).text() === "This a valid host") {
    alert("valid host , panels are enabled");
    $('#text1').attr('disabled', false);
    $('#text2').attr('disabled', false);
    $('#text3').attr('disabled', false);
    $('#text4').attr('disabled', false);
  } else if ($(this).text() === ""){
    alert("Invalid host");
  }
});

setTimeout(function(){
  $("#divoutput").html("This a valid host");
}, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="divoutput"></div>
```

Notice that you can use `$(this)` inside of your callback to refer to the div#output element. You could also probably tidy up all of the references to #text1, #text2, #text3 etc using the [starts with selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/).

Maybe: `$("input[id^='text']").attr('disabled', false);`